# Tree-decomposition with clique interfaces

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, clique, treewidth

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite undirected graph. A *[tree decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition)* $(T,\lambda)$ of $G$ is a tree $T$ with labeling function $\lambda : T \to 2^{V}$ such that:

1. For every edge $\{v_1,v_2\} \in E$, there exists a node $n$ of $T$ such that $v_1,v_2 \in \lambda(n)$.
2. For every vertex $v \in V$, the set $\{n \in T \mid v \in n\}$ forms a connected subtree of $T$.

For my purposes (namely, showing the tractability of model-checking for a particular logical fragment), I am interested in a restricted kind of tree decompositions, that satisfies an additional condition. I call a *tree-decomposition with clique interfaces* a tree decomposition $(T,\lambda)$ of $G$ that respects the following additional property:

- For every two adjacent nodes $n_1$ and $n_2$ of the tree decomposition $T$, we require that the *interface* $\lambda(n_1) \cap \lambda(n_2)$ forms a clique in $G$. In other words, for every pair of distinct elements $a,b$ occurring both in $n_1$ and $n_2$, we must have $\{a, b\} \in E$.

As usual, the *width* of such a decomposition is $max_{n \in T}|\lambda(n)|-1$ and the *width* of $G$ is the minimal width of such a decomposition.
Note that, of course, the width of $G$ according to this definition is necessarily greater than its treewidth in the usual sense.

My question is to know **if this notion of width has already been studied and has an established name**. In particular, I am interested in alternative characterization of graphs whose width is low in this sense, in the complexity of computing it, etc.

This could be related to the notion of *[$k$-trees](http://dmg.tuwien.ac.at/drmota/DAHeinz.apdf)*. In k-trees, we impose in tree decompositions that $\lambda(n)$ forms a clique for all $n$ and that the interfaces are of size $k$. However not all graphs have such a decomposition, while for the notion that I propose, all graphs would have a decomposition (at worst the trivial one with width $|V|-1$) so it looks like this notion could have been studied in a general context.

Comment: I think these decompositions correspond to what Diestel calls "simplicial decompositions" (see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X89900848) but I don't know if the width is considered in this part of the literature.

Comment: Because of this name, perhaps "simplicial width" or "simplicial treewidth" could be appropriate names for this width parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See ["Decomposition by clique separators", Robert E. Tarjan, *Discrete Mathematics* 55 (2): 221–232, 1985](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(85)90051-2).

If I understand correctly, your notion of width is essentially the size of the largest piece in Tarjan's decomposition.