# Complexity of computing the simplicial width of a graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, clique, treewidth

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite undirected graph. A *[tree decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition)* $(T,\lambda)$ of $G$ is a tree $T$ with labeling function $\lambda : T \to 2^{V}$ such that:

1. For every edge $\{v_1,v_2\} \in E$, there exists a node $n$ of $T$ such that $v_1,v_2 \in \lambda(n)$.
2. For every vertex $v \in V$, the set $\{n \in T \mid v \in \lambda(n)\}$ forms a connected subtree of $T$.

For my purposes (namely, showing the tractability of model-checking for a particular logical fragment), and following my [earlier question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34089/tree-decomposition-with-clique-interfaces), I am interested in a restricted kind of tree decompositions, that satisfies an additional condition. I call a *simplicial decomposition* a tree decomposition $(T,\lambda)$ of $G$ that respects the following additional property:

- For every two adjacent nodes $n_1$ and $n_2$ of the tree decomposition $T$, the *interface* $\lambda(n_1) \cap \lambda(n_2)$ forms a clique in $G$. In other words, for every pair of distinct elements $a,b$ occurring both in $n_1$ and $n_2$, we must have $\{a, b\} \in E$.

As usual, the *width* of a simplicial decomposition is $max_{n \in T}|\lambda(n)|-1$ and the *simplicial width* of $G$ is the minimal width of a simplicial decomposition.
Note that, of course, the simplicial width of $G$ is necessarily greater than its treewidth in the usual sense.

My question is to know whether the complexity of the following two problems is known:

- **computing the simplicial width together with a simplicial decomposition**, i.e., given as input an undirected graph $G$, compute the simplicial width $w$ of $G$ and a simplicial decomposition of width $w$;
- **computing, for a fixed width, a simplicial decomposition of that width**, i.e., for a fixed constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$, given as input an undirected graph $G$, computing a simplicial decomposition of width $\leq k$ if one exists, and outputting "no" otherwise.

For the usual notion of treewidth, the known complexities are the following (but they don't give bound for simplicial width):

- **computing the treewidth** of an input graph (even without a decomposition) is [NP-complete](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0608024) ([open access link](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~jan.ramon/MiGraNT/arnborg.pdf));
- **for any fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$, computing a tree decomposition of width $\leq k$** [can be done in linear time](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=243727) ([open access link](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/MISC/BIBLIOTECA/trunk/Arnborg/Arnborg5.pdf)).

The name of simplicial decomposition is introduced in ["Simplicial decompositions of graphs: a survey of applications", Reinhard Diestel, *Discrete Mathematics* 75 (1-3): 121-144 1989](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X89900848) and is the same as that of "decomposition by clique separators" in ["Decomposition by clique separators", Robert E. Tarjan, *Discrete Mathematics* 55 (2): 221–232, 1985](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(85)90051-2). However, it seems that the notion of simplicial width is not studied here. There is a similar notion of *clique minimal separator decomposition* for which a quadratic bound is known ([here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/lirmm-00485851/document) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390510Z)) but it doesn't seem to be exactly the same problem (I think it minimizes the size of the *separators* between bags, not the size of the bags).